# Template: How to return container of container

Tags: c++, c++11

I would template a function in order to use it with vector, set, or anyone else container of the STL (having the correct API...)

My function current prototype is:

```
vector<vector<int>> f ( const vector<int> & v, int size ) {...}
```

I tried different kind of declaration, like the following:

```
template<template<typename U, typename Alloc> class C, typename T>
C<C<T, Alloc>, Alloc> f (const C<T, Alloc>& v, int size)
{...}
```

But I don't find the the correct way to write that. Can you help me ?

Comment: Which `Alloc` do you want for your returning container (the outer one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
template<template<typename...> class C1, template<typename...> class C2, typename T, typename... Args>
C1<C2<T, Args...>> f (const C2<T, Args...>& v, int size)
{...}
```

to allow different containers or

```
template<template<typename...> class C, typename T, typename... Args>
C<C<T, Args...>> f (const C<T, Args...>& v, int size)
{...}
```

if the inner and the outer container need to be identical or maybe just:

```
template<template<typename...> class C, typename T>
C<T> f (const T& v, int size)
```

and access `T::value_type` instead of `T` in the above first example.

It's hard to give better advice as the use-case is unclear from your question.

---

Update: to explain why your attempt didn't work:

```
template<template<typename U, typename Alloc> class C, typename T>
C<C<T, Alloc>, Alloc> f (const C<T, Alloc>& v, int size)
{...}
```

look at it and think again: First of all you need `Alloc` as another parameter as the names of the parameters in the template template parameters are not usable for anything. This would lead to:

```
template<template<typename T_dummy, typename A_dummy> class C, typename T, typename Alloc>
C<C<T, Alloc>, Alloc> f (const C<T, Alloc>& v, int size)
{...}
```

better, but now you have a real problem: The allocator for the inner container is something like

```
std::allocator<int>
```

which is suitable for the inner container, but not for the outer one which needs something in the line of

```
std::allocator<std::vector<int>>
```

hence the attempt to re-use the inner allocator for the outer container is doomed to fail.

Comment: Thank for your answer and useful information on how template argument deduction work. As my output container type will be of the same form of the input I used your second proposal ("inner and outer container need to be identical"). To add some context, you can have a look [here](http://ideone.com/lQeQ8n) to see how i use it, the goal was to write a template function to extract all subset of any kind of container having "insert" function! Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You may want:

```
template<template <typename, typename> class Container, typename T, typename Alloc>
Container<Container<T, Alloc>, typename Alloc::template rebind<Container<T, Alloc> >::other>
f(const Container<T, Alloc> & v, int size ) {
    // Your implementation
    //return {{}};
}
```

As Daniel Frey mentioned, Allocator cannot be the same for inner and outer container,
so above code `rebind` the allocator to a correct one.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Thanks, fixed with `rebind`... but not as generic :/